# Setup Log4j 2 in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, log4j2

I am trying to set Log4j 2 in my web application (Tomcat 9.0, Java Version 11, Netbeans). I read many tutorials and I think I have set it up right. I am not getting any errors, but also I don't get any logs... So, I have misconfigured something. What I have done till now:

1. I downloaded the jar files `log4j-core-2.14.1.jar` and `log4j-api-2.14.1.jar` and I added them in project's **Libraries** (I am not using Maven, what I did is to right click on **Libraries** and then **Add JAR** in Netbeans.
2. I created a `log4j2.xml` file and I placed it inside of `WEB-INF` folder. The xml file contains:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="File" fileName="C:/WebApplication/logs/info.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.mkyong" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
   </Configuration>
   ```
3. Then in my servlet I added :

   ```
   public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

       private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HomeServlet.class);

       protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
           //etc

           System.out.println("Hello 0");
           logger.info("Hello from Log4j 1");
           logger.debug("Hello from Log4j 2");
           logger.warn("Hello from Log4j 3");

           //etc
       }
   }
   ```

I run my application and I am getting `"Hello 0` but I am not seen any other log message. Also in the folder `C:/WebApplication/logs/info.log` there is none file there...

Also, in web.xml I added the following, but still nothing..

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j2</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

What I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: I think it is Windows Path problem. Have you tried relative path like `fileName="info.log"` ?

Comment: I tried, still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

By default Log4J looks for its configuration on the classpath. The WEB-INF directory is not on the classpath so the file will not be found. You can either place the file in WEB-INF/classes or configure your web app with the location of the file.

For example, you can configure the location in your web app with:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///etc/myApp/myLogging.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This example shows using a file url. A good practice would be to have the configuration outside of your application. For example at ${catalina_base}/mycorp/conf/log4j2.xml. This allows you to change the configuration without having to mess with the innards of the deployed app and allows it to persist across deployments.

The full documentation can be found on the [Log4j web site](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html#ContextParams).

Comment: I tried it (I updated the question) but nothing happened. Can you elaborate a little more how I configure my web app to see the place of the xml file?

Comment: I am using an iPad so don’t have access to the code. Configuring a context parameter is correct but the param name is wrong. Also, the path will likely be relative to Where Tomcat is installed so you will need to include ${catalina_home} as part of the path